# How to plan SharePoint global and departmental sites?

Tags: sharepoint-online, administration

My company has 3 departments: HR, Finance, IT.

I have following windows groups:

1. Win_HR - contains all HR staff
2. Win_Finance - contains all finance staff
3. Win_IT - contains all IT staff
4. Win_allstaff - contains all staff

I have a need to upload documents into SharePoint such that Departmental files should be accessible only for the department staff. Certain documents must be accessible by all company staff.

What is the better approach to action this:

1. One site collection with 4 document libraries (common, finance, HR, IT). Permission to be broken at library level.
2. One site collection with 4 sites. Each site will have 1 document library. Permission to be broken at site or library level.
3. 4 site collections. Each with 1 document library. Permission to be broken at site level or document library level
4. Hub site